# php - translating "%C3%BC" to ü

Tags: php, utf-8

In a page, I have this reference:

`<a href="Schulte_Einf%C3%BChrung.pdf">Page</a>`

I've written a function to see if the file that is referenced to exists. But in this case, the file is named

`Schulte_Einführung.pdf`

I know that C3 BC is the UTF-8 encoding of ü, but how can I decode `%C3%BC` and turn it into ü? All the usual functions like `utf_decode` and so on don't do anything.

I can't change the filename (because I pull it from a backup file), and I also can't change the encoding because then the page could break. So is there a way to compare `Schulte_Einf%C3%BChrung.pdf` and `Schulte_Einführung.pdf` so that they will be equal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I know that C3 BC is the UTF-8 encoding of ü

It isn't. It is an ASCII description of the UTF-8 encoding.

Since it is data encoded in a URL, use [the `urldecode` function](http://php.net/urldecode).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `urldecode` it, this will give you Ã¼, which is the UTF8-encoded representation of ü, so you should be all good.